# React Hooks state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am unable to update my react hooks state.

So this is what I am doing (this is a minified relevant code).

```
export const Signup = (props) => {
  const key= 'randomKey'
  const onTextChangeHandler = (text) => {
    console.log(key)
    setPayloadData[key] = text
    console.log(payload)
  }
  const [payload, setPayloadData] = useState({})
  return (
   <View>
    <TextInput  
          placeholder={placeHolder}
          number={number}
          style={[{color: defaultColor, borderColor: defaultColor}, styles.defaultTextInputStyle, templateStyle]}
          onChangeText={text => onTextChangeHandler(text)}
          value={payload[key]}
        />
  </View> 
)
}
```

here, In the above code, notice

```
 const onTextChangeHandler = (text) => {
    console.log(key)
    setPayloadData[key] = text
    console.log(payload)
  }
```

Here text is coming out to be whatever I typed. `console.log` of the key is returning the `randomKey` but

```
console.log(payload)
```

Is coming out to be undefined. Can anyone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`setPayload` is a function, not an object. What you are actually doing is assigning a new field to the function, the `payload` remains unchanged, since the function responsible for updating it is **not being called**.

```
setPayloadData[key] = text; // the function object mutation occures
```

**Solution**: simply invoke it as a function and pass the argument you want:

```
setPayloadData({ [key]: text });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** Update state using `useState` hook

**Update props value and HOC components accordingly**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const Signup = (props) => {
  const key= 'userKeyboardStrokes'
  const onTextChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setPayloadData({ [key]: event.target.value })
  }
  const [payload, setPayloadData] = useState({})

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input  
            type="text"
              onChange={text => onTextChangeHandler(text)}
          />

    </React.Fragment> 
  )
}
module.exports = Signup;
```

**Output Result:**

```
{
  userKeyboardStrokes: "user input on object"
}
```

Playground Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-npytvn?file=testing.js

Answer (score -1):

`setPayloadData` is a setter, it should be `setPayloadData(newData)` to update the state.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24848035)

Comment: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" from [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)